# Removing controls from Video tag

Tags: video, html5-video

I'd like to know how to permanently disable the controls on the video tag. 
At the moment I have a 5 second video as sort of an intro to a school project site, and I wish for the video to not have any controls whatsoever (No replay, no pause button or anything like that).

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this? Been scouring the web for quite a bit but I can't seem to find an answer.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

`controls` is a boolean attribute and remains unset if not included. Users don't have the play button anymore so don't forget to set the `autoplay` attribute.

```
<video autoplay>
  <source ...>
</video>
```